# How do I open a pdf file with PDF X-Change Viewer so that I can still modify the pdf source?

Tags: pdf, latex, lock

Whenever I open a pdf file with PDF X-Change Viewer it locks up the source pdf file to edits.  Is there a way to open the pdf (with PDF X-Change Viewer) so that it doesn't lock-up the source file --- perhaps as a shell command with an option?

The background: I use LaTeX to edit my pdf files, and preview the result with PDF X-Change Viewer.  I must first close PDF X-Change Viewer before I can preview any changes I make in the LaTeX source.  It would be nice if PDF X-Change Viewer did not lock-up the pdf source so that I could modify it without first closing PDF X-Change Viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to make PDF-XChange viewer do this. That's the bad news.

The good news is that there are other viewers that will do it, including free-as-in-beer ones. I use [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) on Windows and have been quite satisfied with it. Not only does it auto-refresh, it also keeps track of your view settings and position for all files, which is very handy.

I just wish I could find a PDF viewer for Linux with all the features I want. Will have to fork one of them someday...